# Python to C++ Integration: Passing cv2.VideoCapture to C++ with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, opencv, pybind11

I am working on a project that involves passing a cv2.VideoCapture object from Python to a C++ function using cv::VideoCapture, leveraging a pybind11 wrapper.

I have posted a minimal reproducible example [in this repository](https://github.com/gsaponaro-af/opencv_pybind11_mre).

Essentially, the C++ code looks as follows and compiles:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace py = pybind11;

void process_video(cv::VideoCapture& cap) {
    // Perform operations on the video capture frames
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    // First try
    //
    // Python method expects a cv::VideoCapture
    // Upon receiving a cv2.VideoCapture, it gives the following error:
    //
    // TypeError: process_video(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    // 1. (arg0: cv::VideoCapture) -> None
    //
    // Invoked with: < cv2.VideoCapture 0x7ff14164fc90>
    //m.def("process_video", &process_video);

    // Second try
    //
    // Python method expects a py::object, it receives a cv2.VideoCapture
    // We need to convert it to a C++ cv::VideoCapture
    m.def("process_video", [](py::object cap_python) {
                cv::VideoCapture cap_cpp = reinterpret_cast<cv::VideoCapture&>(cap_python); // segfault!
                return process_video(cap_cpp);
    });
}
```

In Python, I am trying to use the wrapper as follows:

```
import cv2
import example

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4")
assert cap.isOpened(), "Cannot open video"

example.process_video(cap)

print("End")
```

However, I am encountering an error.

When the naive "First try" method is uncommented, I obtain a TypeError because a cv2.VideoCapture was passed instead of a cv::VideoCapture.

With the "Second try" method, I obtain a segmentation fault, presumably because of a mistake when converting from Python to C++ in the line with the "segfault!" comment.

Any suggestions on how to properly convert a cv2.VideoCapture object from Python to the C++ code (which uses cv::VideoCapture) via pybind11 would be greatly appreciated. I think that I may need to resort to [pybind11 custom type casters](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/custom.html) and to the [OpenCV VideoCapture implementation details](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html), but I am having trouble understanding how to put it all together.

Comment: `py::object` and `cv::VideoCapture` are in no way related, so `reinterpret_cast` makes not sense (let alone casting a value to reference). `py::object` just contains some pointer to a CPython `PyObject` structure. After that, I bet there's at least another level of indirection before you could concievable reach the pointer to the wrapped `VideoCapture` instance... but I haven't dug into the low-level CPython API for a while, that would take some digging.

Comment: The main issue here is that OpenCV bindings don't use pybind, so it won't really help you much. My main question here is "Why do you want to do it this way?". Why not just pass the constructor parameters to the C++ code, and let it create a VideoCapture instance itself? As an alternative, expose `VideoCapture` again using pybind11, providing whatever functionality you need in your usecase.

Comment: you might have to dig around in OpenCV's Python bindings generation to learn how they do it.

Comment: @DanMašek thank you for the feedback and for pointing out some mistakes. Regarding "Why do you want to do it this way?", for now I cannot change the C++ signature `process_video(cv::VideoCapture& cap)`, that needs to accept a `VideoCapture`. However, I have more flexibility in Python, so I will follow your advice to expose a new type `VideoCaptureWrapper` using pybind11, then the Python code will pass an `example.VideoCaptureWrapper` argument.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks, I am checking how OpenCV's Python bindings are generated [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html).